# How can I search google for files with a specific extension and particular file size range?

Tags: google-search

I know that one can search for files with a specific extension with the keyword `filetype`, e.g. [filetype:pdf market study](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Apdf+market+study&oq=filetype%3Apdf+market+study&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.338j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

but I don't know if one can specify a file size range.

So for example, list only PDFs that are within 5MB-15MB?

Comment: [Why is this question on searching for files with a specific extension and some file size range in Google kept closed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5200/18147)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an option and I don't think there would be one.

If there were an option it wouldn't be on the search query form(as that only has the simple options).

If the option were provided by Google for Google search, it'd be one of the options like what Google calls "query prefixes", like `filetype:pdf`, or `inurl:...` as you suggest.

There is a short document from Google here that just covers the basic options  [Google options on the search query form](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)  and it's not there.

Here is a document from Google listing and describing more advanced options,  various query prefixes available [Google Search Appliance, Search Protocol Reference, V7.2 and later](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/xml_reference.pdf). I don't see it there.

A reason why there wouldn't be a file size search option is it'd be open up some vulnerabilities 'cos webmasters can leave files on their web servers that get indexed by search engines and weren't intended to be by the webmaster.

Comment: I agree there's probably no option, but that link doesn't show all the search options 'cos there's loads like inurl:   they call some of them prefixes, see   In-Depth Guide to How Google Search Works 
 https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/xml_reference.pdf

I think a reason why there wouldn't be a file size search option is it'd be open up some vulnerabilities 'cos   webmasters can leave files on their web servers that  get indexed by search engines and weren't intended to be by the webmaster

Comment: @barlop Interesting. Feel free to edit the links in directly. I've made the post community wiki too.

Comment: @barlop I think your username is already attributed as post author: `50% barlop`- so I removed it in body and made the answer of a more uniform theme. I think community wiki answers(or for that matter all answers) should be like Wikipedia articles...Feel free to [edit] to make such changes

Comment: ok, no worries re credit, I just didn't want to change somebody e'se's wording a lot, / rewrite it without their permission,  but if you prefer an edit, and since I see your post was short, so probably you'd be ok with me rewriting it,  i've edited it, to wording the way I'd word it!

Answer (score -2):

If you go to google image and you go to settings and then advanced search than image size you can filter the image size. You can look at the settings to see more filter but that is all Google offers.

Comment: I believe image size may refer to dimensions, not file size.

Comment: A)even aside from the fact that your question refers to images and he gave a particular exampel of PDF.  B) You started your "answer" saying "If you go to google image and you go" That suggests that that's the anwer to his question. But the answer to his question taht you actually mean is No you can't. You should say that in the beginning instead of writing the start of your "answer" as if you can. Also, to really prove that you can't you should link to some documentation of google search functions, so we can see that there is no such option. (cntd)

Comment: (cntd) I think there probably is no such option but you haven't demonstrated that